# Parsing a string containing an Array from a SOAP response in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, parsing, soap

I'm sending a request to a SOAP interface using Savon in Ruby on Rails.

The problem I'm getting is the results are being returned as a string containing an array:

> Array ( [0] => ACCESS [1] => ALLEY [2] => ANCHORAGE [3] => APARTMENTS
>   [4] => ARCADE [5] => AVENUE [6] => BANK [7] => BAY [8] => BEACH [9] =>
>   BELT [10] => BEND [11] => BOARDWALK [12] => BOULEVARD [13] =>
>   BOULEVARDE)

I've tried to parse the results using the Savon function **.to_hash** but this part remains a string.
I've also tried using **Nori.parse** on the string but this returns an empty hash.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem to this while using a SOAP interface? What would be the best approach in order to parse this into a Ruby array?

I figured I'd put the question out there before embarking on writing hacky code using regular expressions to put it into the right format, then calling **eval()** on it.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: So my hacky solution ended up being: `@results.to_s.split("=>").map {|i| [i.gsub(/(\W|\d)/, "")] }[1, @results.length]` Surely there is a better way to go about this.

Comment: The value you're receiving back isn't XML, so you can't parse it with an XML parser. Is that the exact format the value is in, or are there single/double quotes or new-lines anywhere? Are the "values" always single words or can you get multiple values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your result looks exactly like the example, this is how I'd go after the values one of these ways:

```
string = 'Array ( [0] => ACCESS [1] => ALLEY [2] => ANCHORAGE [3] => APARTMENTS [4] => ARCADE [5] => AVENUE [6] => BANK [7] => BAY [8] => BEACH [9] => BELT [10] => BEND [11] => BOARDWALK [12] => BOULEVARD [13] => BOULEVARDE)'
string.scan(/=> ([A-Z]+)/i).flatten
=> ["ACCESS", "ALLEY", "ANCHORAGE", "APARTMENTS", "ARCADE", "AVENUE", "BANK", "BAY", "BEACH", "BELT", "BEND", "BOARDWALK", "BOULEVARD", "BOULEVARDE"]
```

or:

```
string.scan(/\b[A-Z]+\b/)
```

which returns the same result, only allowing upper-case words. If you'll get mixed-case this will fail, and making it case-insensitive will fail because of the leading "Array".